# Quartz Scheduler - multiple process IDs of OC4J running same instance, each gets scheduled

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, oc4j

I have recently tried Quartz to schedule mails. When the application is deployed on the app server, internally it creates multiple process IDs for OC4J instance. When it runs, all these instance run separately and send  mail.

Can I use a JDBC job store to handle this situation? What else I should do to avoid it?

Comment: Quartz allocates a separate thread (worker thread) to run each of your scheduled job. Even though the job is scheduled with simpleschedule with some repeat counts, a new job instance is created for each execution. Could you explain what is your requirement here ? do you want a single instance of job to run at one time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify concurrent as false if you are explicitly starting the job through XML or java code.